# Asus to set USB boot style from UEFI/EFI to BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, asus-laptop, efi

On my Asus laptop,

- I've disabled the Secure Boot Control, and
- I've enabled `[Launch CSM]` (Compatibility Support Module)
- I partitioned my HD using MBR
- All my systems on my Asus laptop are boot from such BIOS/MBR/CSM mode, including Win8 and all my Linux

However, I found that my USB is booted in EFI style, and I have found nowhere in my Asus ***Q400A*** laptop BIOS to change / disable / switch that.

Anyone can help? -- [Because](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583330/this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition)

> boot your recovery live media using the same boot style (either BIOS or UEFI) as was used by the system you're trying to repair;

I need to boot my USB in BIOS/MBR/CSM style to do my boot repair.

Thanks

Comment: The computing world has gone to UEFI and Secure Boot. Your best solution is a fast SSD and then run your non-compliant machines as virtual machines. If there is any chance your machine might run Windows 11 (odds are not) it certainly will not run Windows 11 with old style boot structures.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the confirmation @John, which helps stops me from trying to go further in the wrong direction.